# Disable close button of MSBuild child process

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I have a PowerShell script that launches an MSBuild child process. I would like to disable the "close" button on the child process window, so that the user cannot interrupt the process. However, I have not been able to find any information indicating whether this is possible.

If someone could either confirm (and tell me how I would go about doing this) or deny whether this is possible I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSBuild.exe is a console application, and as such by default it will run in a console window. You can't really "disable" the close button anymore than you could stop someone (with the right privileges) from just terminating the msbuild.exe process...

What you could do to mitigate some risk would be to use the the jobs feature that was introduced in PowerShell 2.0:

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { 
  & msbuild app.csproj
  if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { throw "MSBuild failed. Exit code: $LASTEXITCODE" }
}
```

This will schedule the script block to be run on a background thread of your PowerShell session and it will not show a window for msbuild. All of the output will be captured and held until you decide to retrieve the job. You can check the status of all background jobs with the `Get-Job` cmdlet, and receive the results with `Receive-Job`

```
Wait-Job $job # this line pauses PowerShell/your script until the job returns
$output = $job | Receive-Job
```

You can do whatever you want with the output - it is worth noting that the exception thrown if the msbuild exit status code is non-zero will be held until you receive the job, at which point it will be raised to your code like any other exception would be. You may want to consider wrapping your call to Receive-Job in a try/catch block to deal with a failed build.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming that I can't disable the close button. I know that I can set the WindowStyle of the MSBuild process to Hidden, which will also hide the console window.

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you don't want a separate window to appear:

```
$buildArgs = "MySolution.sln", "/t:Build", "/p:Configuration=Debug"
Start-Process -FilePath "msbuild" -ArgumentList $buildArgs -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

[Start-Process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848%28v=wps.620%29.aspx) has other flags to control redirecting output as well.